# Oraclize pricing in smart contract

Tags: oracles

Should i have ether in contract account in order to call oraclize_query (firtst call is free) or it discounts from the main account?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need the contract to have the Ether at the moment when it calls oraclize. However, it should work whether you pre-pay the contract or pay the contract in the transaction that calls oraclize.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53934/discussion-on-answer-by-edmund-edgar-oraclize-pricing-in-smart-contract).

Answer (score 1):

Seeing by your comments, that you are using truffle, you should be able to send the appropriate ether amount, using a variation of the following:

```
MyContract.deployed().update({ from: myAccountWithEther, value: web3.toWei(0.1, 'ether') });
```

MyContract would be the contract name containing the Oraclize methods.

myAccountWithEther should be an account that contains sufficient ether that can be sent along that you have the ability to send with.